# Insert foreign key column where value is from another table's column in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have two tables "user info" and "user login" where they both have an ID column but the ID column in user info table is an identity type and the ID column of the user login table is referenced to the ID of user info table.

THis is my stored procedure which inserts values to both tables at the same time.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]
@fname varchar(50),
@lname varchar(50),
@gender int,
@bday date,
@address varchar(max),
@city varchar(50),
@zip nvarchar(50),
@country varchar(50),
@status int,
@telhome varchar(50),
@teloff varchar(50),
@mobile varchar(50),

@login varchar(50),
@pass varchar(50),
@email varchar(50),
@pin varchar(50)
```

`AS`

```
INSERT INTO UserInfo
(
Firstname,
Lastname,
Gender,
Birthday,
[Address],
City,
Zip,
Country,
Civil,
HomeTelephone,
OfficeTelephone,
MobileTelephone)

VALUES (@fname, @lname, @gender,
@bday, @address, @city, @zip, @country, @status, @telhome, @teloff, @mobile)

INSERT INTO UserLogin
(
ID,
[Login],
[Password],
Email,
TransPIN
)
VALUES (***THE ID OF NEW UserInfo row**, @login, @pass, @email, @pin)
```

My problem is I have to get the ID generated from the newly inserted row in the user info table to be inserted in the User Login table.

Comment: I tried the "FROM inserted" method but it doesn't work here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign last inserted Id into variable "SET @lastInsertedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" and use this variable in second insert statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]
@fname varchar(50),
@lname varchar(50),
@gender int,
@bday date,
@address varchar(max),
@city varchar(50),
@zip nvarchar(50),
@country varchar(50),
@status int,
@telhome varchar(50),
@teloff varchar(50),
@mobile varchar(50),

@login varchar(50),
@pass varchar(50),
@email varchar(50),
@pin varchar(50)
AS
DECLARE @lastInsertedId INT;
INSERT INTO UserInfo
(
Firstname,
Lastname,
Gender,
Birthday,
[Address],
City,
Zip,
Country,
Civil,
HomeTelephone,
OfficeTelephone,
MobileTelephone)

VALUES (@fname, @lname, @gender,
@bday, @address, @city, @zip, @country, @status, @telhome, @teloff, @mobile)

SET @lastInsertedId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO UserLogin
(
ID,
[Login],
[Password],
Email,
TransPIN
)
VALUES (@lastInsertedId, @login, @pass, @email, @pin)
```

Answer (score 0):

[@@IDENTITY as per Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql)